# How to make sure 'this' inside mocha test have access to class properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

const expect = require("chai").expect;

```
class Test 
{
 constructor(){ this.x= 10;}
 run() {
 describe("test goes here", function() {
  it("sample test", function() {
    expect(this.x).to.be.eq(10);
  });
 });
 }
}

new Test().run();
```

getting x is undefined.

Issue : **this** inside describe points to complete different context, how to make x available to **this** inside mocha test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrow functions `() => this...` or `.bind` on your functions.

```
describe("test goes here", () => {
  it("sample test", () => {
    expect(this.x).to.be.eq(10);
  });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for update, just curious how arrow function is different from regular function ?

Comment: @user522170 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas